# Xcode quit unexpectedly while trying to use a view of height 0.5?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview

I just want to use a view of height 0.5 as a line. when i try to select and move that view, the Xcode quit unexpectedly and shows this message.

[image]

I don't know why this happens. I never had this problem before.

Tried restarting Xcode and System as well.

Using Xcode 8.2, Swift 3.0

**Note:** A view of height 1 or above works good.

Comment: Xcode is not supposed to crash like that. Please report the bug to Apple.

Comment: its the bug from apple

Comment: I tried it with xcode 8.2.1, but couldn't replicate the issue.

Comment: like @Priyal I also tried and didn't found any issue. So report to Apple.

Comment: Oh i see!. i will do. thanks.